# cardinality of any two bases are same

Tags: vector-spaces

How to prove that, any two bases of an infinite dimensional vector space have the same cardinality.
The proof for finite dimensional is easy.
But , I would like to see the most elementary and easy proof of this theorem.Most of the book solves this problem which unfortunately I don't understand.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Infinite dimensional" and "cardinality" _are_ high level mathematics, so I'm unable to understand the question. Explain, please!

Comment: What do you mean by "high level mathematics that you don't understand" and, conversely, what do you mean by "elementary matheatics that you understand"? Most books do that for a reason, and most people learnt that proof from some book: you are very likely to find here the same things you have read, thus wasting your and other people's time.

Comment: G.sassatelli math stack exchange always provides the most excellent proof .how do you expect I will only see the proofs here that I have gobe throgh.I have just seen a proof from goffmen pedrick functional anlysis.I would be happy if ypu kindly explain the proof on my behalf.thank you

Answer (score 2):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Vect}{Vect}$

There is a somewhat easy proof assuming you are familiar with cardinals (and therefore with ordinals):

Let $E$ be a vector space over some field $k$. Let $\kappa$ be an infinite cardinal. Let $X$ be a generating subset for $E$ of cardinal $\kappa$, let $Y$ be a free subset of $E$. Let's prove by induction on $\kappa$ that $|Y| \leq |X|$.

To do this, assume that this is true for cardinals below $\kappa$, and **fix a well-ordering $\leq_X$ of $X$ whose resulting order type is $\kappa$**. Note that if $\kappa = \aleph_0$, this assumption is in fact a consequence of the result for finite families, so we can treat the base case along with the inductive step.

For $x \in X$, define $Y_x:= Y \cap \Vect(x' \in X, x' <_X x)$. Since **any $\{x' \in X \ | \ x' <_X x\}$ has cardinal below $\kappa$** and $Y_x$ is a free subset of $\Vect(x' \in X, x' <_X x)$, by our hypothesis, we have $\forall x \in X, |Y_x| < \kappa$.

$Y = \bigcup \limits_{x \in X} Y_x$ is thus a union indexed by $\kappa$ of sets of size $< \kappa$, **so $|Y| \leq \kappa = |X|$**.

---

You can see that this is not conceptually close to the proof in the finite case (which is arguably easy if one has never seen the argument!), but I actually don't know a proof which doesn't rely on the finite case.

I have put the three parts of the proof that use knowledge about cardinals on emphasis. I doubt you will benefit from studying this theorem without first trying to understand them. If you are mainly interested to the case when $\kappa = \aleph_0$, then those three points should seem more obvious.